# Group by specific token in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so I have my dataframe which is formatted as below.

```
Sentiments.head()

    Sentiment   Tweet
0   0           [corona, updat, govern, vow, pay, wage, staff,...
1   0           [open, today, til, PM, takeaway, beer, need, s...
2   0           [that, call, corona, viru, coronaviru, london,...
3   1           [that, th, person, know, bought, corona, dog, ...
4   1           [hhmmm, colodia, drifu, nigeria, believ, coron...
```

I need to group the tweets, using the token 'govern' and 'Johnson'. I have tried this code below

```
grouped_df = Sentiments.groupby('Tweet')
grouped_df.get_group('govern')
```

However I get an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Both of the columns are added from lists, so is it possible to group by specific tokens or do I need to change the datatypes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want finally have: two groups with first where lists contain both `govern` and `Johnson` and second with rest or something else?

Comment: I want to group by them, so return the dataframe rows which contain the words 'govern' and 'Johnson', maybe it could be in a new dataframe? I need to get the amount of Tweets containing those words and sentiment scores attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

*return the dataframe rows which contain the words 'govern' and 'Johnson'*

This might be done using `set` arithemtic following way, consider following simple example: getting records where both `bb` and `cc` are present

```
import pandas as pd
def has_bb_cc(x):
    return set(['bb','cc']).issubset(x)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c'],'col2':[['aa','bb','cc'],['bb','cc','dd'],['cc','dd','ee']]})
bb_cc_df = df[df.col2.apply(has_bb_cc)]
print(bb_cc_df)
```

output:

```
  col1          col2
0    a  [aa, bb, cc]
1    b  [bb, cc, dd]
```

Explanation: I define function for checking if `bb` and `cc` are present using `set` arithmetic, then I `apply` it to column with `list`s thus getting `pandas.Series` of `True`s and `False`s which I then use to extract records from `df`.

As side note I would call it *filtering* rather than *grouping*.